# JSONP Callbacks in Adobe Air

Tags: jquery, air

I am having trouble figuring out a way to get some data back from a url in adobe air.  It seems that there are security restrictions in air such that doing a normal callback will not work.  So something like:

```
 $.getJSON( requestURL, 
               function(json)
            {
                $('#response').append("working");
            }
          );
```

Doesn't execute the callback.  Is there some way to get around this?  I did find some mention of this and a possible solution at http://css.dzone.com/news/jsonp-request-adobe-air but that doesn't seem to be working for me.  I can run the code just fine in a normal browser but in air it fails to call either the dataFilter or the sucess method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out so I'll just post an answer.  Thanks to the spaz open source twitter client from which I ripped some of this.

```
var xhr = $.ajax({ complete: function (xhr, rstr)
    {
        result = xhr.responseText;
        cleanresult = result.substr(result.indexOf('(') + 1, result.lastIndexOf(')') - result.indexOf('(') - 1);
        object1 = JSON.parse(cleanresult);
    },
    error: function (xhr, rstr) { },
    success: function (data) {},
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {},
    processData: true,
    url: requestURL,   
    type: "GET"}
);
```

This just returns a string so then I used the [json2 library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) to parse it into an object and that seemed to work.  Seems to work across domains and everything.